# True/false : There exist $f : S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ which is continuous and onto

Tags: general-topology

Is the following  statement is true/false ?

> There exist  $f : S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ which is  continuous and onto.

My thinking: yes, because for  every  function $f : S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  there exist uncountably many pairs  of distinct  points $ x $ and $y$  $\in S^1$ such that $f(x) = f(y)$.

Comment: That's not what "onto" means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is wrong. The image of a compact set under a continuous mapping is compact.

Comment: In other words: $f$ has a minimum $m$ and a maximum $M$ on  $S^1$, so that $f(S^1) \subset [m, M]$.